# Error: Cannot find module '/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.31/opus.node

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i've been trying to set up a discord  music bot (https://github.com/moonstar-x/discord-music-24-7)
on pebblehost. but i get the same problem every time. discord.js/opus is installed in the inbuilt package manager but i still get the error. does anybody know the solution to this

```
15.11 21:29:21 [Bot] discord-music-24-7@4.2.1 start
15.11 21:29:21 [Bot] node ./src/app.js
15.11 21:29:23 [Bot] (8:29:23 PM) - [[INFO]] -  Registered Miscellaneous Commands (id: misc) command group.
15.11 21:29:23 [Bot] (8:29:23 PM) - [[INFO]] -  Registered Player Commands (id: player) command group.
15.11 21:29:23 [Bot] (8:29:23 PM) - [[INFO]] -  Registered help in Miscellaneous Commands.
15.11 21:29:23 [Bot] (8:29:23 PM) - [[INFO]] -  Registered skip in Player Commands.
15.11 21:29:25 [Bot] (8:29:25 PM) - [[INFO]] -  Refresh interval has been disabled.
15.11 21:29:25 [Bot] (8:29:25 PM) - [[INFO]] -  Connected to Discord! - Ready.
15.11 21:29:25 [Bot] (8:29:25 PM) - [[INFO]] -  Presence updated to: ◼ Nothing to play
15.11 21:29:25 [Bot] (8:29:25 PM) - [[INFO]] -  Joined Chill Raum in Cocraft.
15.11 21:29:25 [Bot] (8:29:25 PM) - [[INFO]] -  User EmoPlayer has joined Chill Raum.
15.11 21:29:25 [Bot] [WARN]: ytdl-core is out of date! Update with "npm install ytdl-core@latest".
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] /node_modules/prism-media/src/util/loader.js:12
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] throw new Error(errorLog.join('\\n'));
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] ^
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] Error: Error: Cannot find module '/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.31/opus.node'
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] Require stack:
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/@discordjs/opus/lib/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/prism-media/src/util/loader.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/prism-media/src/opus/Opus.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/prism-media/src/opus/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/prism-media/src/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/BasePlayer.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/BroadcastAudioPlayer.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/VoiceBroadcast.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/ClientVoiceManager.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/@greencoast/discord.js-extended/dist/classes/ExtendedClient.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/@greencoast/discord.js-extended/dist/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /src/app.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] Error: Cannot find module 'node-opus'
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] Require stack:
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/prism-media/src/util/loader.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/prism-media/src/opus/Opus.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/prism-media/src/opus/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/prism-media/src/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/BasePlayer.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/BroadcastAudioPlayer.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/VoiceBroadcast.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/ClientVoiceManager.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/@greencoast/discord.js-extended/dist/classes/ExtendedClient.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/@greencoast/discord.js-extended/dist/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /src/app.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] Error: Cannot find module 'opusscript'
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] Require stack:
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/prism-media/src/util/loader.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/prism-media/src/opus/Opus.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/prism-media/src/opus/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/prism-media/src/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/BasePlayer.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/BroadcastAudioPlayer.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/VoiceBroadcast.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/ClientVoiceManager.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/@greencoast/discord.js-extended/dist/classes/ExtendedClient.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /node_modules/@greencoast/discord.js-extended/dist/index.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] - /src/app.js
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] at Object.loader [as require] (/node_modules/prism-media/src/util/loader.js:12:9)
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] at loadOpus (/node_modules/prism-media/src/opus/Opus.js:17:17)
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] at new OpusStream (/node_modules/prism-media/src/opus/Opus.js:46:10)
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] at new Encoder (/node_modules/prism-media/src/opus/Opus.js:149:5)
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] at AudioPlayer.playPCMStream (/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/BasePlayer.js:58:34)
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] at AudioPlayer.playUnknown (/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/BasePlayer.js:53:17)
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] at VoiceConnection.play (/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/util/PlayInterface.js:71:28)
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] at Player.play (/src/classes/Player.js:124:39)
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
15.11 21:29:28 [Bot] at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
15.11 21:29:28 [PebbleHost] Server shut down (running)
15.11 21:29:28 [PebbleHost] Server stopped
```

i tried reinstalling opus and downgrading it but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I think you just must install opus

`npm i @discordjs/opus`